# Hide an image if the url is not valid

Tags: php

Sometimes the $data['filename'] is null or blank. I need the img src="pdf.png" to change to a different image src="no-pdf.png" , or hide when the $data['filename'] is null or blank.

```
<table align="center" border="0" style="font-size: 14px;">
<?php
    $idnum=$_POST['idnum'];
include "dbConn.php"; 
$records = mysqli_query($db,"select * from scan where idnum like '%$idnum%'");
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
?>
  <tr align="center">
    <td><?php echo $data['idnum']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    
    <td id="test"><a href="https://mysite.co.za/image/<?php echo $data['filename']; ?>" target="popup" 
  onclick="window.open('https://mysite.co.za/image/<?php echo $data['filename']; ?>','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
    <img src="pdf.png"  style="width:30px;height:40px;"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    
  </tr> 
<?php
}
?>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if $("#test") = "https://mysite.co.za/image/" then
   $("#test").hide();
</script>
```

``

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been obsolete for over 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<td id="test">
  <?php if ($data['filename'] == null || $data['filename'] == '') { ?>
    <img src="no-pdf.png" style="width:30px;height:40px;">
  <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="https://mysite.co.za/image/<?php echo $data['filename']; ?>" target="popup"
      onclick="window.open('https://mysite.co.za/image/<?php echo $data['filename']; ?>','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
      <img src="pdf.png" style="width:30px;height:40px;">
    </a>
  <?php } ?>
</td>
```